# Programmatically check if PHP is installed using Python

Tags: php, python

Using python, how would I check if PHP is installed on my server (CentOS 6.4)? Most of the googled resources point in the opposite direction, i.e to check if the python module is installed in PHP.

Is there any way to check if PHP (whatever version) is installed on the server using Python?

**EDIT:**
I have written a bash script which simply calls `php -v` and that can be called from within python, but is there any other way in Python directly?

Comment: Unless you want to check for its presence so that you can remove it, I fail to see the point :s

Comment: @ereOn - The point is, if it exists, the python script installs some relevant php modules, if not, prompts the user to install PHP

Comment: @FakeRainBrigand - Sorry, edited post

Comment: i see no problem with calling `php -v`

Comment: @i.h4d35: I think you are overthinking this. First establish "how to detect PHP presence" then implement the solution with anything you like (that can be Python, a shell script or anything really).

Comment: @mnagel - Would this be right? `subprocess.call("php -v",shell='TRUE')`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use subprocess to check if it can execute the command.

```
import subprocess as sp
def hasPHP():
    try:
        sp.check_call(['php', '-v'])
        return True
    except:
        return False
```

Then you can call `hasPHP()` to get either `True` or `False`.

---

Note: while it's usually best to specify an error type, the variety of errors that could come up (different operating systems, etc.) it makes more sense to leave it out.

---

About the `as` syntax:

This line:

```
import subprocess as sp
```

Basically does this (it's slightly more complicated):

```
import subprocess
sp = subprocess
del subprocess
```

In less formal terms, it gives an alias to a long module name.

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
from os import system
php = system('php --version')

if php != 0:
    print 'Missing: PHP'
```

Comment: does this take care of custom locations? i.e if the user has install php sin some custom location and hasn't created links to /usr/bin or /usr/local/bin

Answer (score 0):

If installed, you'll find a php binary `/usr/bin/php` or `/usr/local/bin/php`

To check if a path is an existing file:

[`os.path.isfile(path)`](http://docs.python.org/library/os.path.html#os.path.isfile)

> Return `True` if *path* is an existing
>   regular file. This follows symbolic
>   links, so both `islink()` and
>   `isfile()` can be true for the same
>   path.