# check whther PHP is installed or not in Python?

Tags: php, python

I want to check whether PHP is installed on the server or not using Python.
I read [Programmatically check if PHP is installed using Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18141248/programmatically-check-if-php-is-installed-using-python) thread . If PHP is installed then its ok. if not then I need to get PHP source from php.net and auto install with IMAP and MySQL extentions only if PHP is not installed on server.

I've tried the following code for checking PHP is instaled or not

```
import subprocess as sp

def hasPHP():
    try : 
        sp.check_call(['php', '-v'])
        return True
    except: return False


if not hasPHP():
    #then install php. How do I install php?
```

Comment: And your question is how to install PHP from your Python script? The correct procedure for that is different for every OS & Linux flavour... Perhaps the best solution, is to display a message to the user?

Comment: I'm using Linux. and I want to install on top it. So, how can I do that?

Comment: There's no such thing as a `one Linux OS', there are many different flavours with different package managers & subtleties..

Comment: Ok. So, is there any python script which will let me install php ?

Comment: Have you checked out automation software such as Puppet, Chef..? It can do what you are looking for.